# Android app not showing for tablet in google play

Tags: android

My app is compatible for Google Nexus 7 but not with other tablet like BSNL etc. Is there any way to check in Google play why app not compatible for particular tablet.

Comment: What are your minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion set to?

Comment: minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion is 8

Answer (score 1):

Device Availability on the Google play developer console  provides a dynamic list of compatible devices based upon your manifest settings. therefore its better to start from the manifest file. Check the "uses" permissions.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en&ctx=go&

It could be the case that you may have added some hardware features or incompatible screen size which is not compatible with the Nexus 7.